# How to make user enter a certain format using regex java

Tags: java

```
public static  boolean usernameValidator(String username) {

    String condition = "^[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-z]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(condition);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(username);
    return m.matches();

}
```

I want the user to enter a certain format eg  name.surname so only a-z or A-Z then . then a-z or A-Z again. When I do enter input in the certain format the method returns false. Am I using the syntax wrong

Comment: Just use this in your method: `return username.matches("(?i)([a-z]+\\.[a-z]+)");`. The `(?i)` ignores letter case. If you want to force the first letter of both the name and the surname, then use this in your method instead: `return username.matches("([A-Z][a-z]+\\.[A-Z][a-z]+)");`.

Answer (score 3):

A few things going on here.

As I understand it, you want `username` to contain something of the form: `<letters>.<letters>`.

There are a few things wrong with your regular expression if that is what you are aiming for.

In the second set of square brackets (`[]`), you have written `A-z` rather than `A-Z`, and there should be a `+` afterwards. A `+` indicates you want *one or more* characters. Without it, the `[a-zA-Z]` only matches a single character.

The period is also a special character in regex (meaning *any character*) so you need to escape it with a back-slash `\`, but that is a special character used to escape other characters so you need a double backslash `\\`.

Hence, I think you are aiming for:

```java
public static  boolean usernameValidator(String username) {
    String condition = "^[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(condition);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(username);
    return m.matches();

}
```

I've added the `$` to indicate that you want to match to the end of a line since you have already included the `^` to match the start.

I don't believe either of these are necessary in this case so could reduce the regex to `[A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+`.

If you are new to regular expressions, maybe have a read of one of the following pages:

- [JavaDocs for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [W3Schools Java Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp)
- [TutorialsPoint Java Regex](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)